# Спецификация С++

Tags: c++, c++17

Вот такой вопрос, если взять [эту](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) спецификацию N4713, оня включает в себя всю спецификацию или только изменения? И есть ли ещё подобные спецификауии ктоторые тоже лучше почитать, ну про стандартные либы и что-то подобное.

Comment: А в ней разве не написано?

Comment: Это полный стандарт.

Comment: Ну судя по объёму я подозреваю что это полная версия, но решил уточнить, вдруг есть какие-то дополнения или типа того, просто раньше не изучал экосистему плюсов.

Comment: Если есть сомнения вот 20 итоговый https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf сравните

Comment: Вот тут всегда самый свежий черновик: http://eel.is/c++draft/

Comment: и кстати разве не n4659 17 итоговый???? @HolyBlackCat подскажите плиз

Comment: Не знаю, я не следил, какой был последний.

Comment: Мне вот тоже казалось что N4713 крайний из принятых, или уже есть новее?

Comment: @pnp2000, как уже было отмчено выше, последние изменения в стандарте Вы можете найти здесь: http://eel.is/c++draft/